# what environment variables can override application mode and where do they need to be set?

Tags: magento2, developer-mode, production-mode, environment-variable

When I run `deploy:mode:show`, it shows an application mode followed by a message that says that its value may be overridden.  For example:

```
prod@mysite01:~/www$ ./bin/magento deploy:mode:show
Current application mode: production. (Note: Environment variables may override this value.)
```

Same thing if I set `MAGE_MODE` by hand in the command line:

```
prod@mysite01:~/www$ MAGE_MODE=developer ./bin/magento deploy:mode:show
Current application mode: production. (Note: Environment variables may override this value.)
```

So, what does that note mean?  Can this command ever return `production` when the site is really in `developer` mode, or vice versa?

The reason I'm asking is that we've had cause to question whether our monitoring scripts are working correctly.  We would like to rule this out as a source of confusion.

I'd expect `MAGE_MODE` to be respected.  It doesn't appear to be.